# Using Github's Node-Trello in Ionic 2 - Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'

Tags: angularjs, typescript, require, ionic2, trello

newbee to ionic2, angular2 and programmatic access to Trello.

I would like to use this wrapper in ionic, but can't declare the node-trello module.

I have installed node-trello:

```
npm install node-trello --save
```

which updated my `package.json`:
Please see dependencies section of my package.json "node-trello" has version "^1.1.2"

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.3",
        "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.3",
        "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.3",
        "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.3",
        "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
        "ionic-angular": "2.0.0-beta.10",
        "ionic-native": "1.2.4",
        "ionicons": "3.0.0",
        "minimatch": "^3.0.2",
        "node-trello": "^1.1.2",
        "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
        "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
        "trello": "^0.5.1",
        "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
    }
}
```

Have tried as the author says on his [website](https://libraries.io/npm/node-trello)

```
var Trello = require("node-trello");
```

But I get the following error despite the fact that /node-modules/node-trello directory exists.:

> TypeScript error: C:/workspace/.......etc...../Service.ts(26,22): Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.

Answer (score 0):

You are using typescript, so it should be

```
import Trello = require("node-trello");
```

or

```
import * as Trello from "node-trello";
```

EDIT: this should work at runtime, if your modules are being loaded correctly, however it will still show an error during compilation. To get rid of the error, you have to provide typescript with the module declarations.
Normally you would download the declarations from npm or Typings, but I didn't find them for the node-trello package, so you have to provide your own.
You can put this into your declarations file:

```
declare module "node-trello" {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kuba tried both - they don't work either. Both give error: TypeScript error: C:/workspace.....etc...../service.ts(3,25): Error TS2307: Cannot find module 'node-trello'.

Comment: And does it work at runtime? If it works and the module is found, you can ignore this error. For the error to disappear, you would have to provide typescript with the definitions to the node-trello library. I'm not sure whether they exist, if they do not, you can create a fake definition just to make TS happy. You can add something like this to you definitions file: declare module "node-trello" {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
}

Comment: Hi Kuba. No - errors still stop bundle being generated.

Comment: Hi Kuba.
Thanks for your help. No - it does not run, the errors still stop bundle being generated.
I inserted your declare module block into the index.d.ts where there are other declare module statements. 
Don't get an error now at the require or import line at the top of the file. 

Using adunkman/node-trello in gitlab, I assume I don't need the line var Trello = require("node-trello");  but if I comment it out, I get 
Error TS2351: Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.
On removing comment, I get Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.

Comment: To force Typescript to compile your project even with errors, put noEmitOnError: false to your tsconfig.json file. Do not use var Trello = require("node-trello"); in Typescript, use one of the methods that I wrote in my answer, otherwise it won't recognize the require clause.

Comment: To use new with the declared module, you would have to export a (constructor) function from the declared module. Maybe it would be simpler to just declare the global Trello variable as described in your other question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38495236/using-trello-rest-in-ionic-2-error-ts2304-cannot-find-name-trello/38510562).